# How about an odds and ends stack site?

Tags: discussion

Essentially for all those questions that get bumped from the currently existing sites for being in the wrong place. E.g. if a perfectly good and interesting question has no natural home in the existing family of 'stack' sites it could 'fall off the end' and find a home at an 'odds and ends' catch-all site. A sort of SO reject bin if you like.

You could call it 'orphaned storage'.

Periodically the tag stats could be analysed to sift for promising new stack sites.

Comment: How is babby formed?

Comment: Is today meta-friday?

Answer (score 4):

Take a cue from Jeopardy, and label it:

```
Potpourri
```

Comment: dot stackexchange dot com.

Comment: well yes: potpourri.stackexchange.com stackpourri.com; etc; etc;

Comment: PotpourriOverflow

Comment: I dunno, I think the Potpourri designation is overflow, so it'd be a redundant thing.

Comment: I'd prefer "notes and queries" - but that's the Guardian-reader in me...

Answer (score 3):

There is [OffTopic.SE](http://offtopic.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Wow. Ask and ye shall find. Six whole questions as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Jeff has often stated an opinion that you can't have a site with no topic/focus, it will just end up poorly supporting *everything*. At which point it becomes very hard to build community and get quality, reliable answers. Obviously, you can make what you want with a [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/) site, but I would not expect to see Jeff and his team create an "odds and ends" site.

Comment: Possibly, but I wonder if you would get small sub-communities forming around certain tags. As such you could cut through the noise by focusing on tags you that represent communities you align with. If a specific tag become popular then we can spawn a site specifically for that subject and migrate the questions over. It's a sort of melting pot if you like (there's another potential site name).

Answer (score 1):

So... Who's gonna answer these questions? How do you propose to lure away users from existing general-purpose Q&A sites like Y! Answers or WikiAnswers?